# wrap text inside a div which is inline-block

Tags: css, word-wrap

I have the following html

```
<div >
        <div _ngcontent-c1="" style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle">
            <svg _ngcontent-c1="" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="23px" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 26 23" width="26px" 

xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <title _ngcontent-c1="">ic_report_problem_black_24px</title>
                <desc _ngcontent-c1="">Created with Sketch.</desc>
                <defs _ngcontent-c1=""></defs>
                <g _ngcontent-c1="" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" id="Business-customer-link" stroke="none" stroke-width="1">
                    <g _ngcontent-c1="" id="Desktop-BCP" transform="translate(-378.000000, -117.000000)">
                        <g _ngcontent-c1="" id="ic_report_problem_black_24px" transform="translate(377.000000, 115.000000)">
                            <polygon _ngcontent-c1="" id="Shape" points="0 0 27.8935742 0 27.8935742 27.8935742 0 27.8935742"></polygon>
                            <path _ngcontent-c1="" d="M1.16223226,24.4068775 L26.731342,24.4068775 L13.9467871,2.32446452 L1.16223226,24.4068775 Z M15.1090194,20.9201807 

L12.7845549,20.9201807 L12.7845549,18.5957162 L15.1090194,18.5957162 L15.1090194,20.9201807 Z M15.1090194,16.2712516 L12.7845549,16.2712516 L12.7845549,11.6223226 

L15.1090194,11.6223226 L15.1090194,16.2712516 Z" fill="#65E3F1" fill-rule="nonzero" id="Shape"></path>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;min-width:224px">
           simple text that should wrap around the div instead of falling down to the bottom
        </div>
    </div>
```

When the screen size becomes small I want the text inside the div to start wrapping inside the div until it reaches the min-width.  However what happens is that as soon as the text cannot be displayed on one line the whole div drops to the bottom line.  How do I get the text inside the div to wrap within the div until it reaches the min-width?

Answer (score 2):

The width of `inline-block` div is calculated by "shrink-to-fit", which equals to `min(max(preferred minimum width, available width), preferred width)`. In your case: preferred width is the width of your text, available width is the width of its container. As a result, the width will be calculated to the width of its container if you reduce the width of its container to a value smaller than its preferred width. Plus the width of the icon, they cannot fit in one line. That's why it warped to a new line.

There are few choices you may want to try for your target:

1. Make the `inline-block` div `inline`. Text will normally warped to second line.
2. Use `display` `table` or `flex`, to force the text and icon keeps in one line.
3. Use `max-width: calc(100% - ??px)` limit its width to fit the container.

Answer (score 0):

Place the `inline-block` element inside a `table-caption`, such as:

```
<table>
    <caption>
        <div style="display: inline-block;>
        </div>
    </caption>
</table>
```